# What does "mannered whimsy" mean?

Tags: meaning, sophie-read

What does "mannered whimsy" mean in the following passage taken from *Eucharist and the Poetic Imagination in Early Modern England*
by Sophie Read?

> Marvell does, it is true, come off better from this particular
>   comparison: Crashaw's little bit of **mannered whimsy** cannot compete
>   with the liquid grace of Marvell's simile, even if one acknowledges
>   that this crystallisation (or, perhaps more accurately here, this
>   dissolution—Ricks's choice of term recalls once more the bon-bons of
>   fond critical memory) is a deliberate rhetorical ploy.

(More context available via [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mXNp2Ib4HoUC&pg=PA139).)

Comment: Thanks but I know the dictionary definitions for each term. I am particularly hesitant about the meaning of the word "whimsy" here as it ranges in meaning from "fancifulness," "playfulness" to "impulsiveness," and "eccentricity". Can I paraphrase it as "affected playfulness", for instance or does it mean "pretentious impulsiveness"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context is a discussion of some poetry by [Richard Crashaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Crashaw) (c. 1613 – 1649) and some other poetry by [Andrew Marvell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Marvell) (1621 – 1678). Both belong to a loose group of poets known as the [metaphysical poets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysical_poets). Ingenuity was an important aspect of their poetry.

The relevant passage from Sophie Read's book quotes the following stanza from Richard Crashaw's poem [Wishes to his (Supposed) Mistress](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44061/wishes-to-his-supposed-mistress):

> Each ruby there,
>   Or pearl that dare appear,
>   Be its own blush, be its own tear.

(The author also mentions Crashaw's poem [On the wounds of our crucified Lord](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38550/38550-h/38550-h.htm#V1_1_52).)

The image of a ruby or pearl being its own tear is very ingenious (like many so-called [conceits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceit#Metaphysical)) and, to some readers perhaps, playful. This is probably why Sophie Read calls it whimsical. See [Wiktionary's definition of whimsy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whimsy):

> 1. A quaint and fanciful idea; a whim; playfully odd behaviour.

In literature, metaphysical poetry is regarded as an example of [mannerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannerism#Mannerism_in_literature_and_music), a term that is first and foremost associated with painting. In that sense, the above example from Crashaw's poem can be called "mannered".

Comment: I have the impression (especially when you compare with the following *liquid grace*) that *mannered* here really does mean simply *elegant* or "classy" :)